# Invalid top-level type in JSON write

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization, gcdwebserver

I'm trying to create a simple JSON object but I still get error and I know what's wrong in my code:

```
NSString *vCard = [BRContacts getContacts]; // this is just a string, could be nil
NSDictionary *JSONdic = nil;
if (vCard)
{
    JSONdic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"status",vCard,@"data", nil];
}
else
{
    JSONdic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"0",@"status",@"vCard is empty",@"error", nil];
}
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *JSONData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:JSONdic options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
return [GCDWebServerDataResponse responseWithJSONObject:JSONdata];
```

The exception is

> Invalid top-level type in JSON write

I checked also `JSONdic` and it's not nil in every case.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm curious about how to deploy some JSON data in GCDWebServer, then I could send some JSON request to this mock server and check the response. Would do you mind to give me some reference like code or example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I solved. It was a problem related to this line:

```
return [GCDWebServerDataResponse responseWithJSONObject:JSONdata];
```

this response of **GCDWebServer** doesn't want a JSON `NSData` but a `NSDictionary`: the error is just because `responseWithJSONObject` process the input for create a JSON object (and I passed a JSON "pre-processed" object). So my error is not related to my initial code so I updated it just now for future reference, I solved using:

```
return [GCDWebServerDataResponse responseWithJSONObject:JSONdic];
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html) for similar problem be sure to follow this rules:

> An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following
>   properties:
>
> - The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary.
> - All objects are
>     instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull.
> - All dictionary keys are instances of NSString.
> - Numbers are not NaN or infinity.

Comment: This is really helpful, does it mean we don't need to serialize json data instead ```responseWithJSONObject``` will do it (because responseWithJSONObject process the input for create a JSON object)

Answer (score 3):

I can't say what is the error, because I tried here and worked.

I tried with `NSString *vCard = nil` and `NSString *vCard = @"SOMESTRING"`, both cases it worked.

```
NSString *vCard = @"SOMESTRING"; // this is just a string, could be nil
    NSDictionary *JSONdic = nil;
    if (vCard) {
        JSONdic = @{@"status" : @"1", @"data" : vCard};
    } else {
        JSONdic = @{@"status" : @"0", @"error" : @"vCard is empty"};
    }
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *JSONData = [NSData data];

if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:JSONdic]) {
    JSONData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:JSONdic options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
}
```

Make sure `[BRContacts getContacts]` returning a `NSString`, and I just rewrite to a modern syntax the `NSDictionary` declaration.

Comment: Checked, altro tried with your example code same result :(

Comment: What happens if you log `JSONData`, if I log with `vCard = @"SOMESTRING"` that's what I get:

`> JSONData = <7b0a2020 22737461 74757322 203a2022 31222c0a 20202264 61746122 203a2022 534f4d45 53545249 4e47220a 7d>`

And `error = nil`

Comment: I get `<7b0a2020 22737461 74757322 203a2022 31222c0a 20202264 61746122 203a2022 534f4d45 53545249 4e47220a 7d>` and I don't know why but now also my error is `nil`. Still got the same exception :\

Comment: Hmm, maybe isn't in that part of code. I'm pretty sure this `JSONData` is right.

Comment: Updated the answer, could you check if enter in this `if`

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4:**
Worth Considering

```
JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
```

instead of

```
JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
```